# Dialogflow (dialogflow_v2beta1) adding timezone to detect text intent python

Tags: python, flask, dialogflow-es

hope all is well

I am making a reminder bot for whatsapp. After hitting my head for the whole night and almost all day today I have decided to ask for help.

One thing, the docs are really useless for dialogflow and most links to doc I found on StackOverflow now redirect.

I have been trying to get timezones going, because if I don't add a timezone dialogflow assumes it is the one I have set in there (GMT+2).

Note: I have the beta API arrow key open.

Suppose I post this to my flask app in python with ngrok.

```
{
   "number":"258xx",
   "timestamp":1642262883085,
   "text":"Ljgl"
}
```

Previously, I was calculating time difference and storing it to the db. I would then play a lot of math games and I managed to get the correct time for time difference. The only issue is:

If someone says message me at 10:36 (UTC+1) and my time is 11:35 (UTC+2), dialogflow assumes the time is 10:35 the next day. So this means, that I need to pass timezone with the message so that 10:36 with 'Europe/Warsaw' as an example so it now that it is still referring today and not the next day.

So I have now been trying to directly send to dialogflow. I have user's timezone in firestore which I retrieve eg. 'Africa/Maputo'.

So having checked, you need to add timezone as a query parameter.

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = "something.json"
DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID = 'project-id'
DIALOGFLOW_LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-GB'

def add_timezone():
    resp = request.get_json(force=True)
    print(resp)

    whatsapp_to = resp['number']
    SESSION_ID = f'appname',{whatsapp_to}'


    phone_number = "+" + whatsapp_to
    text_to_be_analyzed = resp['text']

    session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient(credentials=GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS) #took me a while to figure this out thanks to another post on StackOverflow -> nothing else worked...

    session = session_client.session_path(DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID, SESSION_ID)

    text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(text=text_to_be_analyzed, language_code=DIALOGFLOW_LANGUAGE_CODE)

    query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input) #not used in v2beta1 i think
    #get timezone here (removed code as you don't have access to db)
    timezone = "Europe/Warsaw"
    # query_params = dialogflow.types.QueryParameters.time_zone(timezone) #tried never worked
    payload = {
        "session": session,
        'query_input':
            {
                "text": text_input
            },
        'query_params':
            {
                "time_zone": timezone
            }
    }
    response = session_client.detect_intent(payload)
```

Well it gets stuck at response. After a while it throws this error:

```
[2022-01-15 19:21:15,194] ERROR in app: Exception on /timezone [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo X260\PycharmProjects\whatsapp_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 67, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo X260\PycharmProjects\whatsapp_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 946, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo X260\PycharmProjects\whatsapp_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 849, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
    details = "Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: 'str' object has no attribute 'before_request'"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1642267275.196000000","description":"Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: 'str' object has no attribute 'before_request'","file":"src/core/lib/security/credentials/plugin/plugin_credentials.cc","file_line":92,"grpc_status":14}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo X260\PycharmProjects\whatsapp_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 189, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo X260\PycharmProjects\whatsapp_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 69, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: 'str' object has no attribute 'before_request'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo X260\PycharmProjects\whatsapp_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo X260\PycharmProjects\whatsapp_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo X260\PycharmProjects\whatsapp_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo X260\PycharmProjects\whatsapp_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo X260\PycharmProjects\whatsapp_bot\remindme.py", line 70, in add_timezone
    response = session_client.detect_intent(payload)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo X260\PycharmProjects\whatsapp_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\dialogflow_v2beta1\services\sessions\client.py", line 545, in detect_intent
    response = rpc(request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata,)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo X260\PycharmProjects\whatsapp_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\gapic_v1\method.py", line 145, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo X260\PycharmProjects\whatsapp_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 286, in retry_wrapped_func
    return retry_target(
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo X260\PycharmProjects\whatsapp_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 204, in retry_target
    six.raise_from(
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.RetryError: Deadline of 220.0s exceeded while calling target function, last exception: 503 Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: 'str' object has no attribute 'before_request'
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jan/2022 19:21:15] "POST /timezone HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Any help is appreciate :)

Edit 1:
I tried again, this time I tried new things:

```
    timezone = profile['time_zone']
    session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient(credentials=GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS)
    session = session_client.session_path(DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID, SESSION_ID)
    text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(text=text_to_be_analyzed, language_code=DIALOGFLOW_LANGUAGE_CODE)
    query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)

    query_params = dialogflow.types.QueryParameters(timeZone=timezone)
    response = session_client.detect_intent(session=session, query_input=query_input, query_params=query_params)
```

But error:
`ValueError: Unknown field for QueryParameters: timeZone`
See here: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/QueryParameters

The docs have a field timeZone? So how do I go about it?

```
{
  "timeZone": string,
  ...
```

Edit 2: So it is python so I took a guess and made the timeZone as time_zone and the error is gone. now it shows:

```
    timezone = profile['time_zone']
    session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient(credentials=GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS)
    session = session_client.session_path(DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID, SESSION_ID)
    text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(text=text_to_be_analyzed, language_code=DIALOGFLOW_LANGUAGE_CODE)
    query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)

    query_params = dialogflow.types.QueryParameters(time_zone=timezone)
    response = session_client.detect_intent(session=session, query_input=query_input, query_params=query_params)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: detect_intent() got an unexpected keyword argument 'query_params'
```

Good news is -> I now have query parameters working and figured out how to add timezone to them. Now the question lies on how to actually get it to the intent.

Edit 4:
Credentials were not working out. So I used it as an environment variable.
So now at least without query_params I no longer get the error:
`503 Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: 'str' object has no attribute 'before_request'`

Fix:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = "secret.json"
DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID = 'project-id'
DIALOGFLOW_LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-GB'
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
```

and then in the client i no longer pass credentials.

`session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()`

Edit 5:
Well things run now but does seem like it isn't reading the query_params.

```
timezone = 'America/New_York'
payload = {
                  "session": session,
                  "query_params": {
                      "time_zone": timezone
                  },
                  "query_input": {
                    "text": {
                      "text": text_to_be_analyzed,
                      "language_code": "en-GB"
                    }
                  }
                }
    response = session_client.detect_intent(payload)
```

My time is at GMT+2 so saying 7pm (which is over) would make it the next day 7pm (dialogflow). However, it still isnt 7pm in new york so it should give me the same date as today. This means that it is still assuming my timezone.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally figured it out.

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = "secret.json"
DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID = 'project-id'
DIALOGFLOW_LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-GB'
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
SESSION_ID = f'your_unique_session_id' #to maintain context it should be unique to each user e.g. phone number
session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()
session = session_client.session_path(DIALOGFLOW_PROJECT_ID, SESSION_ID)
timezone = 'America/New_York' #get from your db etc.
text_to_be_analyzed = 'legendaryace' #get from request
payload = {
              "session": session,
              "query_params": {
                  "time_zone": timezone
              },
              "query_input": {
                "text": {
                  "text": text_to_be_analyzed,
                  "language_code": "en-GB" #if diff don't forget to change
                }
              }
            }
try:
    response = session_client.detect_intent(payload)
    print("Query text:", response.query_result.query_text)
    print("Detected intent:", response.query_result.intent.display_name)
    print("Detected intent confidence:", response.query_result.intent_detection_confidence)
    print("Fulfillment text:", response.query_result.fulfillment_text)
except:
    #do your thing
```

That is 3 days of my life figuring out timezones for Dialogflow using python :) Hope you don't have to go through the same :)